# VS code is unable to delete Runner.app while running flutter project external storage

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I use Macbook Air that has only 120 GB of storage. So, while developing flutter application in VS Code, I create all my Flutter projects in external SSD.

Every time I stop debugging and rerun the flutter application, it always throws an error where it is unable to delete the Runner.app directory from the build. This issue is in running the application on physical ios Device.

[image: error screenshot from debug console]

It has a simple solution where I run delete command from Terminal.

[image: Current solution screenshot]

It does seem like a small issue that has a fix as well. But I wonder a lot about it. The issue doesn't arise when running flutter project from internal storage. Does anyone has same problem or better has the solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out. This has to do with format of the external drive. If your external drive is formatted in exFAT and such, there will be this issue while running flutter on Mac. Format your external drive with Apple favourable APFS. Use Disk Utility that is pre-installed with Mac to do so.

Tip: you might wanna back up any important data.

Answer (score 0):

When running in flutter project from external storage in Mac. Ensure that you have given full disk access to you Xcode, Android Studio and VS Code.

Go to Mac's Setting and Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full disk access and check the box for Android studio, Xcode and VS Code.

For save measures, give your Mac a restart. I hope it helps.

[updated]
The problem still persists. I am still stuck with removing the Runner.app manually from a terminal.